# Faking a Method of the Object Under Test

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mocking

Is there a reason why you shouldn't create a partial fake of an object or just fake one method on the object that you are testing of it for the sake of testing another method? This might be helpful to save you from making an entire new mock object, or when there is an external dependency in the method you are faking which you can't reasonably get rid of and would like to keep out of all the other unit tests?

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify - you have object A under test, and object A relies on object B so you want to create a partial fake of object B?

Comment: Read more on mockups and stubs. These techniques are exactly what you are askng about
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_stubs

Comment: You need [Powermock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/). With this you can mock static methods, private methods, constructors, you can really do any magic because it tweaks the bytecode of the classes. This is exactly what you need.

Comment: No, creating a partial fake of object A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Extract and Override* technique described in Chapter 3 of Roy Osherove's *The Art of Unit Testing* does seem to be a way to fake part of the class under test (pp. 71-77). Osherove does not address the concerns raised in some of the other answers to this question.

In addition, Michael Feathers discusses this in *Working Effectively with Legacy Code*. He terms the resulting class a *testing subclass* (227) and the technique *Subclass and Override Method* (401). Now, granted, Feathers is not giving an exposition of pristine techniques that are recommended on new code. But he still gives it serious treatment as a potentially helpful technique.

I also asked my former computer professor about this. He is well-read and currently works full-time in the software industry, where he has advanced rapidly. He said that this technique definitely has a good application, and that there are several dozen classes in the codebase at his company that are under test in this way. He said that, like any technique, it can be overused.

I originally wrote the question when I was new to unit testing and knew next to nothing about dependency injection. Now, after some experience with both, I would add that the need to use this testing technique could be a smell. It may be a sign that need to rework your approach to dependencies. If the method that needs to be faked is one that is inherited from a base class, it may mean that you need to take the adage "favor composition over inheritance" more seriously. You should inject your dependencies rather than inheriting them.

Comment: [Chapter 3 of Osherove is online](http://www.manning.com/osherove/SampleChapter3.pdf) (PDF)

Answer (score 3):

The objects you want to do this for are trying to do too many things. In particular, if you have an external dependency, you would normally create an object to isolate that dependency. The Façade  pattern is one example of this. If  your objects weren't designed with testability in mind you may have to do some refactoring. Take a look at [Michael Feathers' PDF on working with legacy code](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/WorkingEffectivelyWithLegacyCode.pdf)(PDF). He also has a book by the same title that goes into much more detail.

Answer (score 2):

It is a very bad idea to mock/fake part of a class to test another.

Doing this, you are not testing what the real code does in the conditions under test leading to unreliable test results.

It also increases the maintenance burden of the faked part of the class. If this is in effect for the whole test program, the fake implementation also makes other tests on the faked method harder.

You need to ask yourself why you need to fake out the part under test.

If it is because the method is accessing a file or database, then you should define an interface and pass an instance of that interface to the class constructor or method. This allows you to test different scenarios in the same test application.

If it is because you are using singletons, you should rethink your design to make it more testable: removing singletons will remove implicit dependencies and maintenance nightmares.

If you are using static methods/free-standing functions to access data in a registry or settings file, you should really move that out of the function under test and pass the data as a parameter or provide a settings provider interface. This will make the code more flexible and robust.

If it is to break a dependency for the purpose of testing (e.g. faking out a vector method to test a method in a matrix class) then you should not be faking that -- you should treat the code under test as what is defined by the class under test by its public interface: methods; pre-conditions, post-conditions, invariants, documentation, parameters and exception specifications.

You can use knowledge of the implementation details to test special edge cases, but trigger those through the main API, not by faking an implementation detail.

For example, suppose you faked std::vector::at() but the implementation switched to use operator[] instead. Your test would break or silently pass.

Answer (score 1):

If the method you want to fake is virtual (as in, not static and not final), then you can subclass your object in your test, override the method in the subclass, and exercise the subclass in the test. No mock-object libraries required.

(Ideally you should consider refactoring, this is not a great long-term solution. But it is a way to get legacy code under test so you can start the refactoring process more easily.)

Answer (score 0):

There are some really nice packages for facilitating this kind of stuff.  For instance, from the [Mockito docs](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html):

```
//You can mock concrete classes, not only interfaces
LinkedList mockedList = mock(LinkedList.class);

//stubbing
when(mockedList.get(0)).thenReturn("first");
```

does some real magic that's hard to believe at first.  When you call

```
String firstMember = mockedList.get(0);
```

you'll get back "first", because of what you said in the "when" statement.